# Algebraic dependence of the elliptic functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-functions

Let $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be $n$ elliptic functions in $\mathbb{C}$. We say that $f_1, \dots, f_n$ are algebraic dependent over $\mathbb{C}$ if there exists a polynomial of $n$ variables with constant coefficients such that
$$ P(f_1(z), \dots, f_n(z))\equiv 0.$$

What is the sufficient and necessary condition of the algebraic dependence of $f_1, \dots, f_n$.

The case for $n=2$ is known, which can also be found in

[Algebraic relationships between elliptic functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91199/algebraic-relationships-between-elliptic-function).

Is it plausible to  guess that  $f_1, \dots, f_n$ are algebraic dependent if and only if there exist $i$ and $j$ such that $f_i$ and $f_j$ are algebraic dependent. Thank you.